# How to Create a Child with pair tag with QT

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am working on a project where I have to write information in a XML document using QT Library ( QTDomDocument, etc.) for C++.
 It might be stupid to ask, but I am looking for a solution on how to create a XML child node with pair tags, for example, I have this :

```
<color_space>
</color_space>
```

And I would like to add x childs following this schema:

```
<color_space>
   <color_plan>R</color_plan>
   <color_plan>G</color_plan>
    ...
</color_space>
```

I have tried multiple different codes and as far I did, the most similar resultat that I had was :

```
<color_space>
   <color_plan/>
   <color_plan/>
    ...
</color_space>
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: you probably mean <color_space></color_space> since all your XML's are invalid

Comment: yes you're correct, I'll edit that

Comment: Look at [Simple Xml with QXmlStreamWriter](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?key=QXmlStreamWriterWriteXML&index=545). With `xmlWriter.writeCharacters ("myString");` you can write values, like R, G, B

Comment: thank you for you help mate, unfortunately, my entire project is written with QDomDocument library, but will still try with it and QDomDocument if nobody have a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I Just Figured out how to do what I attempted to do, I hope it will help other people!

```
    // Here we have a QVector where we have all our color plan
       QVector<QString>ColorPlanTable= { "R","G","B","L","a","b","Y","Cb","Cr" };

    //sub_element is the Color_space element (parent node)
      sub_element= sub_element.nextSiblingElement();

    // Here we create a new element for color_plan (child of Color_space)
      QDomElement NewColorPlan=document_->createElement("color_plan");

    // And then we create a TextNode to add to the element color_plan
      QDomText NewColorPlanText = document_->createTextNode(ColorPlanTable.at(i));

    // Adding the element color_plan as a child of Color_space
      sub_element.appendChild(NewColorPlan);

    // And then adding the text of the color_plan!
      NewColorPlan.appendChild(NewColorPlanText);
```